# Character set issue

Tags: mysql-5.7, database-internals, mysql-8.0

Error 'Character set '#255' is not a compiled character set and is not specified in the '/user/share/mysql'.

Facing error in replication channel from mysql 8.0.16 to mysql 5.7.25.Is there any solution for it?

My default character set and collation is latin and it is required.